# Blender won’t render the default cube and I can’t cancel the render either

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, osx

New user here doing something that seems very basic.

I open up Blender (2.77) on my Mac (10.13.1). By default, Blender shows me a camera, a cube, and a light. It’s configured to use the “Blender render” but I haven’t changed any rendering settings.

From the main menu I do Render -> Render Image and I get a screen that looks like it’s about to render but then it just... does nothing?

[image]

The progress bar at the top says 0%. If I try to cancel the render by pressing Esc or by clicking the X button on the progress bar, nothing happens. If I quit the app, it says I have unsaved changes but if I “quit anyway” then the app just hangs and I have to force quit it.

My computer is an iMac 5K and I’ve used an older version of Blender on another similar machine, so I don’t think there should be any issues with my graphics card at all.

It seems like I might be missing something but I can’t figure out what. Any ideas?

---

Edit: here’s a picture of my render settings (they’re the same as when I created a new, default project with the cube; I haven’t modified them)

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to upload your blend file? I would need to look around at your render settings. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @icYou520 I’ve added an image of the settings, is this what you meant?

Comment: everything looks ok, I am not sure what it could be, I wonder if the problem would still persist if you tried the latest version of Blender 2.79

Comment: @icYou520 Aha, I figured it out. I had already downloaded 2.79 a few days ago (I think), but I think my Mac was opening an older version I had lying around when I used Spotlight, and that older version either was buggy or was having issues due to the other, newer copy being around. Deleting the older copy fixed my issue. Thanks!